# MySQL Server Stored Procedure AUTO_INCREMENT UNIQUE

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, auto-increment

I am writing a stored procedure in MySQL Community Server 5.5.16 and I need insert there ID which should auto increment and be unique. I am not sure how to do it. Should I use something like this:

```
Declare Z AUTO_INCREMENT UNIQUE;
```

Comment: you are inserting in a table, right?

Comment: yes, 'Insert into Account(Number,Customer,Credit) Values(Here_should_be_id ,pCustomer,0);'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set the field `Number` as `NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT`and in the insert sql `INSERT INTO Account(Customer, Credit) VALUES(pCustomer,0);`